# Re-order three lists and maintain relation between indices?

Tags: python, list

Attempting to create a highscores system that a user can search a name and return all scores achieved by that person and what 'word' (almost like a level/stage) they scored it on. (its a hangman/word guess type game.)

The system I have now has one master list like this importing from text file:

```
word1
score1
name1
word2
score2
name2
...
```

I then split this list into three other lists:

```
list = [ word1, word2 ... ] 

list_scores = [ score1, score2 ... ] 

list_names = [ name1, name2 ... ]
```

(scores are in terms of time, and are floats rounded to 3 decimal points)

The way this works is every element in each list corresponds to the elements in the other two lists of the same index.

```
>>>print "%s solved %s in %r seconds" % ( list_names[0], list[0], list_scores[0] )
Josh solved dog in 1.009 seconds
```

**The task I have is that I want to allow a user to search for names in list_names and then have it return all scores in order based on time, but keep the name and word connection across the lists.**

---

I have tried initially to accept an input and iterate through the list_names to find any matches, and then print the above statement with the same index for all three lists. The problem with this is that it functions how I want it to, but the results are not **in order**.

Here is what I have currently: (apologies beforehand for poorly structured code)

```
search2 = raw_input('>')
print "\n [-- Fastest Times --]\n"
print "  *reload script to update*\n"
  for i,x in enumerate(list_names):
    if search2 in x:
    lni = list[i]
    print "%s - %r seconds by %s" % ( lni[:-1], list_scores[i], x )
```

(the lni[:-1] removes the new line escape from each word)

---

I realize I should use dicts or another system to organize the data, but I have built the whole game around the system and the highscores features have been tacked on in the end to try and be functional with the pre-existing structure of the game.

I plan to go back and rewrite this project once I finish it, so I do indeed appreciate any comments on creating either more efficient or pythonic code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zip, sort, unzip:

```
list_words, list_scores, list_names = zip(*sorted(zip(list_words, list_scores, list_names)))
```

I also renamed `list` to `list_words` to prevent name conflict

[zip documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

To explain the * argument packing, understand the following two calls are identical:

```
function(1, 2, 3)
function(*[1, 2, 3])
```

The list `[1, 2, 3]` is "unpacked", and each element of it passed as argument to the function. So you can easily "reorganize" a list by "unzipping" it:

```
>>> zip(*[[1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c']])
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

*(note that Python 3 requires calling `list()` on this output to see the underlying structure)*

[argument unpacking documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: What is the significance of the ```*``` before ```sorted()```?

Comment: I've added a link to the documentation, but the * before zip's first argument makes it into an "unzip"

Comment: list/tuple unpacking. It turns `[sub1, sub2, sub3]` into `sub1, sub2, sub3` (notice that it's not a list anymore`. So if `L = [sub1, sub2, sub3]`, calling `f(L)` would do `f([sub1, sub2, sub3])`, whereas calling `f(*L)` would do `f(sub1, sub2, sub3)`

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. I dont fully understand why it works but it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Scherf I've added some additional information, as well as a link. Hope this helps!